# Вывод значения из двух строк в одной SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть две таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и
(скрин не всей таблицы)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и мне нужно вывести в одном запросе и имя отдающего и имя получающего в соседних столбцах(по их id)

вот пока что мой код

```sql
SELECT id_операции, id_отдающего, CONCAT(фамилия," ",имя) AS имя_отдающего
FROM barters.barter_operations, barters.clients
where id_отдающего = id_клиента;
```

и результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот я второй день думаю, как это всё вывести, я пробовал и сделать один запрос и к нему потом присоединить другой, и сразу всё в одном запросить, короче, ничего не сработало

Comment: Отдающий и принимающий независимы. Поэтому каждый должен "расшифровываться" по своей, независимой, копии таблицы клиентов.

Comment: @Akina ему бы еще разобраться с `id_отдающего = id_клиента` прежде чем клиентов второй раз добавлять в запрос

Comment: зы: не понимаю в целом людей, которые именуют таблицы и и столбцы на русском, но вдвойне не понимаю, тех кто еще умудряется смешивать русский и английский в рамках названия столбца

Comment: @teran Привет! честно, я не особо понимаю о чем речь сейчас, но замечание про язык учту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
create table clients
(
    id         integer primary key auto_increment,
    surname    varchar(32),
    first_name varchar(32),
    patronymic varchar(32),
    phone      varchar(64)
);
create table deals
(
    id        integer primary key auto_increment,
    seller_id integer references clients on update cascade on delete restrict,
    buyer_id  integer references clients on update cascade on delete restrict
);
insert into clients (surname, first_name, patronymic, phone)
values ('Rahman', 'Sander', null, '336 851-2654'),
       ('Rajiv', 'Martin', null, '846 326-6732'),
       ('Ivanov', 'Oleg', 'Vitalievich', '7 916 312 55 02');
insert into deals (seller_id, buyer_id)
VALUES (3, 1),
       (1, 3),
       (2, 3);
select d.id                                                     as deal_id,
       concat_ws(' ', c2.first_name, c2.patronymic, c2.surname) as seller,
       concat_ws(' ', c.first_name, c.patronymic, c.surname)    as buyer
from deals d
         join clients c on d.buyer_id = c.id
         join clients c2 on c2.id = d.seller_id
```

| deal_id | seller | buyer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oleg Vitalievich Ivanov | Sander Rahman |
| 2 | Sander Rahman | Oleg Vitalievich Ivanov |
| 3 | Martin Rajiv | Oleg Vitalievich Ivanov |

Comment: и зачем путать человека синтаксисом sqllite если стоит метка mysql ? и кейсами этими ему ненужными

Comment: спасибо за ответ! он сработал, мне лишь немного нужно было подправить его на свой лад

Comment: @teran, и велика ли разница за исключением того, что в sqlite отсутствует concat?. Просто мне негде было тестить mysql я им не пользуюсь, предпочитаю postgres

Comment: *велика ли разница за исключением того, что в sqlite отсутствует concat?* В данном случае в MySQL надо использовать CONCAT_WS() и не заниматься фигнёй с кейсами. *мне негде было тестить mysql* Ещё скажите, что не знаете, что такое online fiddle.

Comment: @Akina. Исправил.

Comment: @teran Исправил